# Create bootable Ubuntu USB on a partition, instead of overwriting the entire USB drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, live-usb

I have a 64 GB USB pendrive with two partitions, of approximately 10 GB (the first) and 54 GB.

I'm on macOS, and I know how to create a bootable USB drive by using `diskutil erasedisk` and then `dd` to copy the latest Ubuntu installer .iso image to the USB device. This removes any previously existing partitions and then sets up the entire UBS drive as one single bootable volume.

Is there also a way to keep the 2nd partition unharmed, and just only the first 10GB partition to set up the Ubuntu installer, in a way so that the device still becomes bootable?

I can also remove the 10GB partition and create a smaller one or something else in its place, if that's required. But I just would like to keep the 2nd partition (the 54GB one) as-is.

Comment: Mac is UEFI and newer computers are UEFI. If you do not need BIOS boot. UEFI only USB key, just extract ISO ( 7 zip or similar) to FAT32 formatted flash drive partition & set boot flag.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media  The dd method overwrites standard partition table (eraseing drive) in making hybrid DVD/flash drive installer. The installers that do not use dd, do the format & extract, but normally format entire flash drive as assumed to be smaller and just for the install. But they also add BIOS boot loader, syslinux.

Comment: UNetbootin makes an installer for Mac. It will install the bootable OS to a flash drive partition, and works both BIOS and UEFI. https://unetbootin.github.io/

Comment: @oldfred In this case I'm also looking for a way to do it without UEFI. Is that possible?

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Thanks, I'm just wondering if there's a way to do it with plain shell commands, i.e. a combination of `diskutil` and `gpt` and `dd` or something? Perhaps the same as UNetbootin does, but in separate manual commands, so I understand exactly what's happening in this process?

Comment: With a Mac you really want UEFI. But you can do the same thing as the UEFI only extraction, but also then install syslinux boot loader which is the boot loader used by the Ubuntu installer for BIOS boot.

Comment: @oldfred The thing is, I'm preparing this USB installation disk from macOS, but the actual intended machines to install this on are two barebone PCs. One of which is older and doesn't have UEFI. I'm not sure what you mean by "install syslinux boot loader", is that a file I can copy, or do I have to mess with diskutil or gpt or something create a bootable partition..? (if these are stupid questions or doesn't make sense: I'm kinda unfamiliar with the inner workings of this)

Comment: this is syslinux. But the installer has the configuration files, you only want the boot loader in the MBR. https://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=SYSLINUX. It would then just be mbr.bin to install to MBR. I have not use it as I always use grub and its loopmount to directly boot an ISO. Then you can have more than one ISO on one flash drive. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot  Might be easier just to back up data on flash drive. And you should have back up anyway.

Comment: It is easy enough to boot an ISO, if that works for you? Just need to install grub2 on the disk and loop mount the ISO.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Sorry I have no idea how to pull that off, or what that even means, exactly. Would you have some guidelines maybe? I'd love to learn.

Comment: @RocketNuts: I have never used an Apple product and can not guarantee my answer below works on a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

**SIMPLE mkusb ISO Booter**

It is easy to boot operating system ISO's on a modified mkusb flash drive.

Use mkusb to make a Persistent USB drive using a default OS of your choice, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

Make a folder in the usbdata partition sdx1, named ISOs.

Add the ISO('s) to be booted to this folder.

Add menuentries to /sdx3/boot/grub/grub.cfg to loopmount the ISO's.

Samples:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu-18.04 64-bit ISO" {
    set root=(hd0,1)
    set isofile="/ISOs/ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso"
        loopback loop $isofile
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile splash --
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}

menuentry "GParted 64-bit ISO" {
    set root=(hd0,1)
    set isofile="/ISOs/gparted-live-0.31.0-1-amd64.iso"
    loopback loop $isofile
    linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live union=overlay username=user config components noswap noeject toram=filesystem.squashfs ip='' nosplash findiso=$isofile splash --
    initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
}

menuentry "Clonezilla 64-bit ISO" {
    set root=(hd0,1)
    set isofile="/ISOs/clonezilla-live-2.5.5-38-amd64.iso"
    loopback loop $isofile
    linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live live-config nolocales edd=on nomodeset ocs_live_run=\"ocs-live-general\" ocs_live_extra_param=\"\"   ocs_live_keymap=\"\" ocs_live_batch=\"no\" ocs_lang=\"\" vga=788   ip=frommedia nosplash toram=filesystem.squashfs findiso=$isofile splash --
    initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
}
```

If you don't need persistence you can delete the casper-rw partition.

You can keep or delete the ISO9660 partition.

The usbdata partition can be expanded or shrunk to suit.